# Push notifications are displayed too briefly on locked screen

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

When our app is running and then the screen is locked or turned off, the push notifications are displayed for a brief moment and immediately disappear.

I disabled all the code that handles them (the "DidReceive..." delegate call), just to make sure it isn't our code that causes this behaviour.

I've seen some questions about it but couldn't find any helpful answer. Does anybody knows how to make them stay for a while longer?

Comment: you can't. Push notifications are handled by the OS, until the user interacts with it. This means you, as a developer, have no control over display, duration etc.

Comment: Thanks. I thought so too, but then I decided to test the behaviour in WhatsApp. I launched WhatsApp, turned off the screen and sent myself a message from another device. The screen came alive, displayed the message, and the message notification stayed on the screen - exactly the behaviour we would like to achieve. How do they do this?